# How to use Behaviour Subjects in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am using a service to save one value and used in another component.
this is my service,

```
 export class PageService {
  template_type$:Observable<any>;
  private myMethodSubject1 = new BehaviorSubject<any>('hi');
  constructor() { 
   this.template_type$ = this.myMethodSubject1.asObservable();
  }
  template_type(selectedType){
    this.myMethodSubject1.next(selectedType);
   //console.log(selectedType);
   }
 }
```

in my function i send value to this service,

```
 this.pService.template_type('one');
```

and in another funtion in the same component i call this service to get value

```
 this.pService.template_type$.subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

but it return 'hi' first,, after the function call it return the value..but i need value in first...any wrong in my code ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "but i need value in first"?

Comment: when i call the service i need the value 'one' not 'hi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to use a `BehaviorSubject`, but instead a `ReplaySubject(1)`:

```
private myMethodSubject1 = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
```

This doesn't have an initial value.

Comment: is it return 1  ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: in ReplaySubject<any>(1) ;     here we pass one parameter(ie ,1 ) so when we call this service is it return 1 ?

Comment: The `1` just means that only one value will be retained. You can refer to the rxjs documentation to learn about the constructor parameters.

Comment: Is it Possible to define more than one method in one service ?  when i use more than one function inside a service it will return recent updated value to all